# Do we use "into" or "onto", for example, "put the slide into/onto the platform" when there is only 10% of the slide getting in?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image]

There is a high platform and a slide, and to join them together we have to put the tiny sticking-out bit of the slide into the hole of the platform as shown in the picture.

That tiny bit occupies about 5 or 10% of the slide.

Do we use "**into**" or "**onto**", for example, "**put the slide into/onto the platform**" when there is only 10% of the slide getting in?

**Note:**

If we use more specific terms like "**tab**" and "**slot**", then then it is obvious that we say “**into**”, for example, “**put the tab into the slot**”.

However, if we use general terms “**slide**” and “**platform**”, then we say “**put the slide into the platform**” or “**put the slide onto the platform**” when only 10% of the slide getting in?

Comment: You are not putting the slide 'onto' the platform if you are attaching it by a tab into the side. I would say 'Attach' or 'connect the slide to the platform'.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question:

> put the slide **into** the platform

Comment: But many native speakers think that "put the slide into the platform" means the whole slide got inside the platform. But here, there is only 10% of the slide going into the platform